# Running the console from a VM or EC2 instance in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

So, i'm trying to create a small javascript application that is able to access the console from a virtual machine or an EC2 instance. I know this has been done before, but i could not find any projects or tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this by using the code [here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-create-a-simple-web-based-chat-application/) as a basis

It didnt take much reinventing atall